# Django 3.1+: (fields.E180) SQLite does not support JSONFields

Tags: django, sqlite, jsonfield, django-3.1

I have created a Django project with the new `JSONField` announced in Django 3.1, which supports all databases.

I have successfully used this field on a linux machine, but running `python manage.py migrate` with the same project on Windows fails with the following message:

```
(fields.E180) SQLite does not support JSONFields.
```

The same versions of Python and Django are used in both PCs.

Comment: For MariaDB 10.1.x users: `JSONField is supported on MariaDB 10.2.7+, MySQL 5.7.8+, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and SQLite 3.9.0+ (with the JSON1 extension enabled)`. Details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField

Answer (score 23):

For using `JSONField` with Django 3.1+ and sqlite, the [`JSON1` sqlite extension must be installed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField).

To enable JSON1 on sqlite follow the instructions on Django's wiki: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/JSON1Extension.

Instructions for Windows:

**Edit**: As of Python 3.9, the official Python installer on Windows already includes the JSON1 extension by default.  **Upgrade your python version to solve this issue**.

For Python 3.8 and below:

- Check your python installation - is it 32bit or 64bit? run: `python -c "import platform;print(platform.architecture()[0])"`
- Download the [precompiled DLL](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) that matches your Python installation (32-bit or 64-bit).
- Locate your Python installation. By default, it should be in `%localappdata%\Programs\Python\PythonXX`, where XX is the Python version. For example, it's located in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37`. If you added Python installation directory to your PATH environment variable, you can run the command `where python` on a command prompt to locate it.
  Enter the DLLs directory in your Python installation.
- Rename (or delete) `sqlite3.dll` inside the `DLLs` directory.
- Extract `sqlite3.dll` from the downloaded DLL archive and put it in the `DLLs` directory.
- Now, the JSON1 extension should be ready to be used in Python and Django.

Comment: What can we do if we want to just store json as string? This is a massive burden just for development.

Comment: Actually it should take about one minute to follow the instructions above and you get an amazing jsonfield. You can use a textfileld or find another implementation for a jsonfield - there are a few of them available

Comment: You were right, install instructions were quite simple, and in fact it was just Windows the one that required some extra setup.

Comment: It does not work for me on windows 10. I have replace dll but still getting the same error. Any idea ?

Comment: It does not work for me on windows 10. I have replace dll but still getting the same error. Any idea ?

Comment: This instructions actually worked just fine for me.

Comment: It actually works and took a little time.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem while trying to apply migrations of django-allauth module; and switching to new version of Python solved it.

According to Django site, version should be 3.9+.
https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/JSON1Extension